# Not able to delete inactive record

Tags: trigger, delete

I have a custom checkbox on Contact and I am implementing something like: if the contact is edited AND the checkbox (api name active __c) is not checked then it should be deleted.

I have written below trigger but its not working and most irritating part is its not giving any error also

```
 if(trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Contact con : trigger.new){

            lstAccId.add(con.AccountId);
        }

        for(Account acc : [select id, Count_of_Active_Contacts__c, Count_of_Inactive_Contacts__c from account where id in : lstAccId]){


            for(contact con : trigger.new){
                Contact contact  = new Contact(Id = con.Id);
                if(contact.AccountId == acc.id){
                    if(contact.active__c == FALSE){
                         lstcontact.add( contact );
                        system.debug('---------------contact------------->'+contact);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
delete lstcontact;
        }
```

please help

Comment: @Ashwani It certainly can work (I've personally done this). However, this trigger still looks odd, so I think there's something deeper going on here.

Comment: @ashwani - it will work because i am using this "Contact contact  = new Contact(Id = con.Id);"

if i would not have used this . then it must have given error

Comment: @sfdcfox - could you suggest me how u have done this?

Comment: Yes, if runs on after update not before update. It looks odd as the approach of query contacts and filtering contacts may cause governor limit issues in future. And I don't like the `delete` :) @sfdcfox

Comment: could you suggest me what might be the issue?

Comment: @sfdcfox Has given you the solution.

Comment: @AnkitaSingh DougB and myself have both observed why the code is failing. It's a simple mistake, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new contact, then comparing that new contact's account ID (which is always null), to a value in the query, which is always not-null.

Here's a version that would work:

```
if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
    Contact[] deletes = new Contact[0];
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        if(!record.Active__c) {
             deletes.add(new Contact(Id=record.Id));
        }
    }
    delete deletes;
}
```

There's no need to query the accounts at all, unless you were doing something else with that data. In that case, you can just query the accounts like this:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
    [SELECT Id, Count_of_Active_Contacts__c, Count_of_Inactive_Contacts__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new)]);
```

You can get the account details directly from the map in this case:

```
for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    Account relatedAccount = accounts.get(record.AccountId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you !!its works like charm ..but could you let me know if i can make my code work or what was issue in my code..just for future reference

Comment: @Ashwani That sort of criticism really shouldn't be in public commentary like this. We're supposed to be friendly people here.

Comment: @AnkitaSingh As I've already stated (as well as Doug), you're comparing a NULL value to a NON-NULL value, which will never be true, and thus will never work. You'd observe this effect if you ran a unit test across your trigger (there would be no code coverage from `if(contact.active__c == false)` on).

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have this

```
Contact contact  = new Contact(Id = con.Id);
if(contact.AccountId == acc.id){
```

You are not setting a value for contact.accountId so it will never match and go into the if part

Comment: how can i set the id there?